# Is theme validation required for Bigcommerce's Stencil theme development

Tags: bigcommerce

When using "stencil bundle" is it required to have validated code? It seems it wont export unless the errors are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, yes. But as a temporary solution while in development you can always add some entries to the .eslintignore file ([as specified here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/bundling-and-submitting-a-theme)) present in your root folder. You will have some already there for reference. That will be useful for plugins and modules not written by you that ESLint might not let pass. ;)

Comment: is there a tool to format/fix/beautify it to be valid? Is this normal to require validation, or is that BC or node stack?